# Автодобавление строк и присваивание значений из списка/кортежа

Tags: python

Подскажите как можно реализовать автоматическое добавление строк в программу:

1) Переменная "a" input ('текст') —- далее нужно проверить эту переменную "a" в заданном списке/кортеже ("b")-— если переменная отсутствует, то добавить ее в список ("b'')

2) И как сделать присваивание к значениям из списка допустим если: а=('Ваз','Газ') , b = input(), и если b='ваз' (из списка a), то с = x (*или будет равным соответствующему значению из другого списка или кортежа)

Ps: знаю что это задача для школьников младших классов, но я начинающий и просьба сильно не стебаться. Я и сам знаю что ещё очень туповат в Python. Но надеюсь добрые люди помогут разобраться

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, даже если вы только начинаете изучать Python, неплохо приводить в вопросе свой код.

```
a = ("ГАЗ", "ВАЗ", "МАЗ")
b = "УАЗ" #имитируем b=input().upper()
c=0 #какая-то еще переменная
if b not in a: #проверяем, есть ли b в a, и, если нет, добавляем
    a += (b,)
    c += 1 # делаем что-нибудь с какой-то переменной

print(a, c)
```

> ('ГАЗ', 'ВАЗ', 'МАЗ', 'УАЗ') 1

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = ["ВАЗ", "ГАЗ"] #список с автомобилями
d = ["ням", "трям"] #список для с
b = input("Введите значение: ")
if b not in a:  #если нет b в списке a,
    a.append(b) #добавляем в конец списка а, наше b
    print(a)
else:           #иначе
    c = d[0]    #в с присваиваем первый элемент списка d
    print(c)
```

Тоже, как вариант.